Expo SQLite using assetSource cannot read existing tables
I have created a sqlite database file with a single table in it. I have added this file to the assets folder of my Expo project but when I query the database using the latest expo-sqlite I get a 'no such table ... ' error. Also querying the sqlite_master table returns nothing.
As described in the documentation I am using the SQLiteProvider context
<SQLiteProvider databaseName="mydatabase.db" assetSource={{assetId: require('../assets/mydatabase.db')}}>
    <Body />
</SQLiteProvider>

Given that the sqlite file is intact and definitely contains the table and its data - why can I not use the database in the app? I am testing using Expo Go. Thanks

I renamed the database file and this fixed the issue. As mentioned in the post below there must be some kind of caching in play that means if you update an asset file it doesn't necessarily update what's being used in Expo Go.
Thanks to this post for helping me solve this: React Native - Expo SQLite returns mixed up values for columns
